# What does /root/.bashrc do?

Tags: bash, root

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="/root/.pyenv"' >> /root/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> /root/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> /root/.bashrc
. /root/.bashrc
```

Can someone please help me understand what this script do? or maybe point me out to a documentation that has a better explanation.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually find an explanation here under the section **Basic GitHub Checkout**:

https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

Quoted from webpage:

> Define environment variable PYENV_ROOT to point to the path where
>   pyenv repo is cloned and add $PYENV_ROOT/bin to your $PATH for access
>   to the pyenv command-line utility.
>
> ```
> $ echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile
> $ echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
> ```
>
> Zsh note: Modify your ~/.zshenv file instead of ~/.bash_profile.
>   Ubuntu note: Modify your ~/.bashrc file instead of ~/.bash_profile.
>
> Add pyenv init to your shell to enable shims and autocompletion.
>   Please make sure eval "$(pyenv init -)" is placed toward the end of
>   the shell configuration file since it manipulates PATH during the
>   initialization.
>
> ```
> $ echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
> ```

If you want to learn more, you should probably read this page at the section **Invoked as an
interactive non-login shell**:

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

Comment: Hey Mike, Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

From  bash's manual page (`man bash`):

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc  and   ~/.bashrc [...]

Recommended reading: [6.2 Bash Startup Files](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC71) from [Bash Reference Manual](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html)